# Is it possible to make a social link share counter

Tags: facebook, twitter, counter, social-media

Hey there:) Is it possible to make a counter for how many who shared your website on facebook and twitter?

I'm thinking to structure the code like this. They only see "facebook" and "twitter" as links, + the counter of how many have shared already.

```
<!-- social media share links -->
<a href="javascript:myPopup('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://url.dk')" `   class="facebook-share-wrap">Facebook</a>`
<a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=Share%20awesome%20link">Twitter</a>
<!-- Add Facebook + Twitter shares -->
<p>0 shares</p>
```

Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a public API endpoint for Twitter:

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=
```

E.g.

```
https://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=https://code.google.com/p/pts-mini-gpl/wiki/StaticPython
```

Will return

```
{"count":2,"url":"https:\/\/code.google.com\/p\/pts-mini-gpl\/wiki\/StaticPython\/"}
```

That URL has been shared 2 times.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer :) I'll take a look at it, and see if I'm able to make it.